# Convert date format in file

Tags: sed, awk, date

I have a file with the current date format

11.22.33.44 - - [**2019/08/02-01:23:50+0000**] GET www.

1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888 - - [**2019/08/02-01:28:18+0000**] GET www.

And i need to convert the format to like below. There are thousands of lines in the file.

I have tried a couple sed awk scripts, but cannot get the right format, or any format.

11.22.33.44 - - [**02/Aug/2019-01:23:50 +0000**] GET www

1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888 - - [**02/Aug/2019-01:28:18 +0000**] GET www.

Answer (score 0):

The dateutils package (http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) may help with this